# Cannot convert undefined or null to object GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, graphql

I'm currently learning GraphQL and trying to make a Firebase API with GraphQL. I followed a tutorial on youtube, did exactly the same steps as the guy in video, except I get an error.

**index.js**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const express = require('express')
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express')
const serviceAccount = require('./permissions.json')

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: '...',
})

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Cat {
        name: String
        lifespan: String
        weight: String
        description: String
    }

    type Query {
        cats: [Cat]
    }
`

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        cats: () => {
            return admin
                .database()
                .ref('cats')
                .once('value')
                .then((snap) => snap.val())
                .then((val) => Object.keys(val).map((key) => val[key]))
        },
    },
}

const app = express()
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/', cors: true })

exports.graphql = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

The I run `npm run serve` and try out a query on the GraphQL server. I then get the following error: **Cannot convert undefined or null to object**. I cannot find any solution on the web explaining what I'm doing wrong. I think it has to do something with the Object.keys(..) part of my code.

[image: The error]

[image: Firebase Database]

Does anyone know my mistake, all the help is well appreciated!

Comment: probably `val` is not an object? check it ... ` .then((snap) => {console.log(snap.val()); return snap.val();})` - API/server console

Comment: Yeah snap.val() is `null` but I can't find why. I did everything as explained in this tutorial: https://medium.com/@lukepighetti/yes-you-can-query-firebase-with-graphql-e79a45990f22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I added data in the wrong Database. I added data inside the Cloud Firestore DB instead of adding it to the Realtime Databases.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data being returned is Null, hence this error. Check if you have proper connection to firebase , also have valid dataformat. According to the logic of extraction data, the json returned should be in this form
{"cats" : [{"name" : 'abcd'},
{"name" : 'abcd'},
...
]
}